# call a function if nightmare waitTimeout exceeded

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, nightmare

Using nightmareJS, is there any way to call a function if the waitTimeout limit is exceeded? Right now it is giving me a promise rejection warning

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: .wait() timed out after 10000msec
```

I was wondering if there is any way to call a function if this error is received. My code is structured like:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');       
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true, waitTimeout: 10000});
nightmare.goto(my_url);
nightmare.wait(my_element);
nightmare.evaluate(function() {...});
nightmare.then(function(result) {...code that could give a promise warning...});
```

I could add a catch clause to the goto and then statements (as Belfordz recommended), and this would work, but the then statement has other nested then statements inside it. Id prefer a single statement that can catch any promise warnings or timeout errors thrown.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to add a catch clause to what ever promise is rejecting

Answer (score 0):

The error means that `my_element` is not found on the current page within the delay of 10 seconds.

However, the way you have coded it, you are calling the methods `goto`, `wait`, `evaluate`, `then` synchronously, while they should be called by the internal promise mechanism, i.e. by "chaining" the calls, otherwise they get executed to soon:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');       
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true, waitTimeout: 10000});
nightmare.goto(my_url) // <-- don't end the statement here, continue the chain:
    .wait(my_element)
    .evaluate(function() {...})
    .then(function(result) {...});
```